# How do make a SQL hierarchy that can reference prior data entry in single SQL subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, hierarchy, circular-dependency, intersystems-cache

How do I create an SQL that can use a hierarchy of data (via pivot data) and build a sub-query that can reference back to a prior record, matching on a id. The id can have one or more assessment type(s), I need to retrieve all assessment_type that have no NO exiting "6-month reassessment" record. If the same id has another reference to, say, an "6-month assessment" then skip. I only need the id row that does not have a prior record(s) in the assessment_type field.

The data example is below: id, date_of_assessment, assessment_type.
The SQL that created this data layout is inside the code example.

```
id     date-of_assessment assessment_type
1      2019-09-06         Initial
2      2019-09-06         Initial
1      2017-06-23         6-Month Reassessment
2      2017-09-01         6-Month Reassessment
3      2017-09-09         Initial
```

```
SELECT a.patid as id, date_of_assessment, 'Initial' assessment_type
  FROM cw_cans_assessment a INNER JOIN DCFS.CANS c ON c.patid = 
 a.patid
  WHERE Type_Assessment_Value = 'Initial'
UNION ALL
SELECT a.patid as id, date_of_assessment, '6-Month Reassessment' 
assessment_type
 FROM cw_cans_assessment a INNER JOIN DCFS.CANS c ON c.patid = 
a.patid
  WHERE Type_Assessment_Value = '6-Month Reassessment'
UNION ALL
    SELECT a.patid as id, date_of_assessment, 'Transition/Discharge' 
assessment_type
  FROM cw_cans_assessment a INNER JOIN DCFS.CANS c ON c.patid = 
a.patid
  WHERE Type_Assessment_Value = 'Transition/Discharge'
```

Expected result: all others that have a prior or after (date wise) will be excluded.

```
id     date-of_assessment assessment_type
3      2017-09-09         Initial
```

Comment: from above query you're getting the output mention at the top.....now you want to get all records except `3      2017-09-09         Initial`...because it is next to `2      2017-09-01         6-Month Reassessment`...which is `6-Month Reassessment`.

Comment: using WinSQL on Cache database (Epic Systems)

Comment: no, I need a filter that excludes any other ID's that have more than 1 assessment_type, e.g, a filter that only accept one assessment_type. For example: id=3 2017-09-09 Initial :: is valid since it does not have any corresponding assessment_types rows connected to the id=3; the other id's have two (or more) assessment_type rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this. As the result shown in above query, you are getting some part of your result from above query, just there are some extra records are coming in the result.

And you stated that "Expected result: all others that have a prior or after (date wise) will be excluded.". so you need a filter to exclude all of the dates less then the last `6-Month Reassessment` record. So we group your record in a subquery and filter the record on behalf of `date_of_assessment` as follows.

```
SELECT  id, date_of_assessment, assessment_type FROM (
    SELECT a.patid as id, date_of_assessment, 'Initial' assessment_type
    FROM cw_cans_assessment a INNER JOIN DCFS.CANS c ON c.patid = a.patid
    WHERE Type_Assessment_Value = 'Initial'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.patid as id, date_of_assessment, '6-Month Reassessment' assessment_type
    FROM cw_cans_assessment a INNER JOIN DCFS.CANS c ON c.patid = a.patid
    WHERE Type_Assessment_Value = '6-Month Reassessment'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.patid as id, date_of_assessment, 'Transition/Discharge' assessment_type
    FROM cw_cans_assessment a INNER JOIN DCFS.CANS c ON c.patid = a.patid
    WHERE Type_Assessment_Value = 'Transition/Discharge'
) AS TAB 
WHERE TAB.Id NOT IN (SELECT a.patid FROM cw_cans_assessment a 
                     INNER JOIN DCFS.CANS c ON c.patid = a.patid
                     GROUP BY a.patid, Type_Assessment_Value HAVING COUNT(a.patid)>1 )
```

**EDIT**:- 
As you said that you want to filter all the records whose total count is less then 2, so we filter the records on basis of count of individual id, you may change group by in last to apply more filter.

Comment: no, I need a filter that excludes any other ID's that have more than 1 assessment_type, e.g, a filter that only accept one assessment_type. For example: id=3 2017-09-09 Initial :: is valid since it does not have any corresponding assessment_types rows connected to the id=3; the other id's have two (or more) assessment_type rows.

Comment: thanks all that was tremendous help; I combined a few techniques to deliver the final assessment answer today. Working on my Master of Data Science for full time Data Scientist roles

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query is what you are looking for:

```
select t1.id, t1.date_of_assessment, t1.assessment_type
from mytable t1
where t1.id not in
(
select t2.id
from mytable t2
where t2.assessment_type = '6-Month Reassessment'
)
```

Comment: thanks I will test it on Tuesday and let you know results here

Comment: I may need to add more conditionals, below, such that: a COUNT() of the number of assessment_type that are associated with the id; then only select when the COUNT() = 1. As in id=3, there is only 1 accessment_type